# Rewriting Gaussian r.v. $Z$ as sum of two independent Gaussian r.v.

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose, $Z$ is Gaussian r.v. assume that it has mean 0 an variance 1.

My question is can $Z$ be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
Z=\rho Z_1+(1-\rho)Z_2
\end{align*}
where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 1 and 
$\rho \in (0,1)$?

Does  anything pathological happens with $\rho=1$ or $\rho=0$?

Comment: With $\rho = 0$ or $1$, the identity becomes the trivial one: $Z=Z$

Comment: By $Z= \varrho Z_1 + (1-\varrho) Z_2$ you mean equality almost surely (not in distribution), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general we cannot expect this; at least if we do not want to extend the given probability space.

**Counterexample:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space where $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(Z)$ for some standard Gaussian random variable $Z$. Then we cannot decompose $Z$ as the sum of two independent Gaussian random variables, i.e. write

$$Z = \varrho Z_1 + (1-\varrho)  Z_2,$$

since the only measurable random variables are of the form $f(Z)$ for Borel-measurable functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, what every I wrote is wrong?